# Reactjs hot reloading with electron

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron, webpack-dev-server

I have cloned [this repo](https://github.com/wkwiatek/react-hot-loader-minimal-boilerplate) for reactjs development with hot reloading enabled. 
Its working fine, Problem is that, I want to run this app inside electron with hot reloading. So in my main.js file I pointed reactsjs index.html file. Its showing blank page. Though i can see  tag contents "Welcome to react" on electron window, that means its pointed properly, but no contents are getting displayed.

I found out that electron is throwing error

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND   app.js
```

I am pretty new to react development (started 3-4 days back only), so not sure how to I solve it. Below is my dir structure and webpack config

My app is running at `http://localhost:8080/`

**Directory structure**

```
project
---node_modules
---src
------index.js
------Components  
*babelrc
index.html (used by react)
main.js (used by electron)
package.json
webpack.config.js
```

**Webpack config**

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    'app': [
      'babel-polyfill',
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      './src/index'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You are getting the error because the index.html is referencing app.js in it's initial script tag. Webpack should output a file called app.js into your dist directory. Could it be a permissions issue?

Comment: I just noticed that there is no ./dist folder created nor app.js file is there, but then question comes why react app works fine in browser, its confusing. No there shoudnt be any permission issue because i am on local pc.

Comment: that's odd, worked for me straight out of the box.

Comment: Can you please post it to git, so i can clone and compare.

Comment: Literally just followed the link in your post

Comment: Did you tried to integrate it with Electron ? That repo strait away works great as i have mentioned in my question, but when i point Electron start page to reacts index.html, Electron shows blank page with error for app.js in electron window console. I am also giving it a another try by setting up everything from beginning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149212/discussion-between-www-amitpatil-me-and-calle-bergstrom).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok finally I managed to solve it. Problem was with "webpack-dev-server", this command creates app.js bundle file but doesnt actually place it in your directory. It serves from memory, that's the reason it wasn't getting generated and my electron app wasn't able to find it. I am posting solution here in case any beginner faces the same.

Just go to package.json and replace webpack-dev-server with webpack with `--watch` param, they work almost the same. Difference is that `webpack --watch` will create a actual bundled file and will place it in directory you specified in config.

This doesnt work

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack-dev-server --hot --history-api-fallback --open",
    "app": " ./node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron ."
  },
```

Below works

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --watch",
    "app": " ./node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron ."
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

to run react-hot-loader you should add it in a module in webpack.config.js as the following

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: ['react-hot-loader/webpack','babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
```

also you shouldh add it in .babelrc as the following :

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "react"
    ],
    "plugins": [ "react-hot-loader/babel" ]
}
```

Comment: Hot reloading is working fine in browser, issue is its not showing anything in electron window.